# Will in-update prompt be shown, if newer version has lower priority?

Tags: android, in-app-update

Recently, I started to use in-app update prompt library: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates.

I wonder a case and couldn't find answer for it. My question:

Let's say I have these versions:

- v1 with priority 0
- v2 with priority 1

`appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()` will return v2 of my app, so that I will show the prompt for the v2.

Let's say I released a new version:

- v3 with priority 0

In that case, will `appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()` still return v2 or will return true?

It can return true for v2. But after I released v3, v2 should not be available anymore right? So it can return false. I am not sure which is the correct one.